# Is there an easy way to use host resources (eg. AWS-CLI) in a docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I have a docker container with some Jupyter Notebooks in it, and the notebooks do some processing that involve interacting with AWS, like sending data to and from S3.

I am new to docker, and am wondering how I can send the data in this container to S3. It seems like there would be an easier way than installing AWS-CLI on my container because it's already installed and configured on my host laptop... but what do I know!

If the standard way of doing this is to install AWS on my container I could do that, it just feels redundant.
Thanks

Comment: You can setup a shared folder between your container and a host laptop. So all the files are created in the container are also available in your host laptop.

Comment: I am more interested in sending files directly to AWS, or launching EC2 instances from my container.

Comment: If so, then you can use  boto3 sdk for Jupyter notebook (`python kernel`), or install  `bash kernel` for AWS CLI. `python kernel` will also give you access to bash so you can use aws cli, but it is limited in comparison to running full `bash kernel` in Jupyter. And yes, installing boto3 or aws cli in the container is how you usually do it. The question of how you pass credentials to it, is a different story.

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that containers aren't dependent on particular programs being present on the host or not, and that containers can't steal credentials from the host.  (In an EC2 context, a container can access the EC2 metadata service and use the host's IAM instance credentials.)  The container setup needs to be completely self-contained, and if you're calling the AWS CLI directly there, you ned to install it in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the AWS CLI as part of the container build.

By doing this you can ensure that everything the application needs to run is running in the container, using a mounted volume would cause issues if one the AWS CLI was not on the host machine.